# Adding data to json object dynamically using angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

**This is MY program for dynamically adding name contact to json data**
The program is working fine and showing adding data my list objects while running the program  but the problem is  data can't be saved in my program
Please help to me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="Myapp">
 <head>
 <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width,intial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\java practice\bootsrap\bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="D:\java practice\bootsrap\bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="D:\java practice\bootsrap\jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\java practice\bootsrap\bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="D:\java practice\bootsrap\bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="D:\java practice\bootsrap\jquery.min.js">
  </script>
 <script src="D:\java practice\angular\angular2.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
<div ng-controller="Mycntrl">
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
Name:<input type="text" name="Name" ng-model="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Name">
Contact:<input type="text" name="contact" ng-model="contact" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact">
<ul ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-show="Myshow">
    <li>{{person.name}}</li>
    <li>{{person.contact}}</li>
</ul>
</form>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="Show" ng-click="Myfun()">Show</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="Save" ng-click="save()">Add Contact</button>
</div>
  <script>
var app=angular.module("Myapp",[]);
  app.controller("Mycntrl",function($scope) {
      $scope.name="";
      $scope.contact="";
      $scope.Myshow=false;
      $scope.persons=[
      {name:'Macha Devendher',contact:'1234567890'},
      {name:'Macha Devendher1',contact:'9876543210'},
      {name:'Macha Devendher2',contact:'1472583690'}
      ];

$scope.save=function() {
    if($scope.contact.length<10)
    {
        alert("Please enter valid contact number");
    }
    else {

    $scope.persons.push({ 'name':$scope.name,'contact':$scope.contact });
    $scope.name="";
    $scope.contact="";
    alert("You are contact number added succesfully");
    }
    }
    $scope.Myfun=function() {
       $scope.Myshow=!$scope.Myshow;
    }
  }
 );
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to save persons data in file,database or localstorage ?

Comment: What do you mean its not saving, as in when you reload the page the data is not persisted?

Comment: What is the problem with when you are trying to save?

Comment: Yes ,i want to store data in my localstorage i.e just like with in htis file  myjson.js

Comment: @macha devendher what u want to do? do u want to persist permanently in database, save temporary into local storage?

Comment: you can use websql/local storage or indexeddb to store data locally.

Comment: @TechnoCrat Save Temporarily in localstorage

Comment: Then do it. Here's the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle my *localstorage* I created a neat little service API. It can write, delete, clear and use timestamps to expire objects.

Maybe this will help you:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * storage wrapper for session- or local-storage operations
 */
app.factory('StorageService', function(
        $rootScope,
        $http,
        $location) {

    /**
     * get an item
     *
     * @param item - string - the item identifier
     * @return - mixed -
     */
    var get = function(item) {
        return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(item) ||localStorage.getItem(item));
    };

    /**
     * set an item
     *
     * @param item - string - the item identifier
     * @param value - mixed - the value to set
     * @param usePersistentStorage - boolean - the flag for session- or local-storage
     * @return void
     */
    var set = function(item, value, usePersistentStorage) {
        var obj = {
            value: value,
            ts: new Date().getTime()
        };
        window[usePersistentStorage ? 'localStorage' : 'sessionStorage'][value === null ? 'removeItem' : 'setItem'](item, JSON.stringify(obj));
    };

    /**
     * remove an item
     *
     * @param item - string - the item identifier
     * @return void
     */
    var remove = function(item) {
        set(item, null, true);
        set(item, null);
    };

    /**
     * clear the whole session- and local-storage
     *
     * @return void
     */
    var clear = function() {
        sessionStorage.clear();
        localStorage.clear();
    };

    /**
     * check if item has expired
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    var checkExpiration = function(str, minutes) {
        var now = new Date(),
            nowts = now.getTime(),
            item = get(str);
        if(item && typeof item.ts != 'undefined' && (new Date(nowts) - new Date(item.ts) < minutes * 60 * 1000)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            remove(str);
            return false;
        }
    };

    return {
        get: get,
        set: set,
        remove: remove,
        clear: clear,
        checkExpiration: checkExpiration
    };
}
```

);